# MongoDB: Combining results from two queries

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 queries that generate the following 2 result sets

**Result I**
{ 
    "_id" : "A", 
    "Desks" : 
        [
            "IT1", "IT3
        ]
}

**Result II**
{ 
    "_id" : "B", 
    "Desks" : 
        [
            "IT1","IT2","IT3","IT4"
        ]
}

I would like to build a query that excludes result set I from result set II. What are the constructs available in MongoDB to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use $lookup "leftouter join" Check out this documentation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! will check out $lookup